# TimerTask class does not recognized

Tags: java, ide

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to use timers. My IDE doesn't recognize
`TimerSchedulePeriod` (I have `import Java.util.*`) or even class `TimerTask`

```
TimerTask tasknew = new TimerSchedulePeriod();
```

How can I make my IDE recognise it?

Comment: what Java version and IDE are you using? try to rebuild the project. Go to project properties and check the Java JDK version.

Comment: Hi, I have java version 8 update 25. I have same problem with Netbean , Eclipse and even run without IDE. Is it really a matter of update ?

Comment: I also did rebuild but not help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this,

```
import java.util.Timer; 
import java.util.TimerTask; 

class Helper extends TimerTask 
{ 
    public static int i = 0; 
    public void run() 
    { 
        System.out.println("Timer ran " + ++i); 
    } 
} 

public class Test 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 

        Timer timer = new Timer(); 
        TimerTask task = new Helper(); 

        timer.schedule(task, 2000, 5000); 

    } 
}
```